# Display simple text on vertices

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glew

So I am trying to make a simple program (I'm a student) and it works fine so far, but I can't figure out how to display the "i" value from the loop in the drawCircle() function in Shapes.cpp

code:

http://pastebin.com/4kDPNjy8

example:
[image]

When I compile my code right now it looks like on the image to the left, but I want to get something like on the right but I have no idea how to do that kind of stuff or what function should I use for that.

Please help

Comment: Could you please add the code to the question itself? Source on off-site places could get deleted and the question would not help other people then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, char(i));
```

Should do it. But before that, you probably want to calculate position of each number, so do it, and then call:

```
glRasterPos2f(X_pos, Y_pos);
```